# create nickname by email Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I have to create a nickname from the email address of the user.
For example:
mario-rossi79@gmail.com

in this case the nickname that I have to create should contain only alphanumeric characters:
mariorossi79

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Please note that `mario-rossi79@gmail.com` and `mario-rossi79@yahoo.com` can be two different persons that would like to use your service.

Comment: @moose, What about mariorossi79@yahoo.com and mario-rossi79@yahoo.com?

Comment: Using regexs to validate email addresses or even combining the two in any way is really not the best thing to do. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$email =  'mario-rossi79@gmail.com';
$arr = explode("@", $email);
$result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $arr[0]);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Does the + do anything in your regex?

Comment: @7stud + is used for one or more occurrence of character.

Comment: Without the +, your solution would fail, yes?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in 2 passes. first remove the `@domain` second remove the none alpha numeric.

```
$email = "mario-rossi79@gmail.com";
$user = preg_replace("/@.*$/", "", $email);
$nickname = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $user);
```

Comment: Thanks @DevZer0 your code is perfect. This will work with any email right?

Comment: potentially yes as long as the email address has a `@` separating.